# Multiple urlProviders on the same oauth setting in ktor with keycloak

Tags: authentication, web, oauth-2.0, keycloak, ktor

I am making a ktor web application with keycloak as auth.

```
val keycloakProvider = OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
    name = CLIENT_NAME,
    authorizeUrl = KEYCLOAK_AUTH,
    accessTokenUrl = KEYCLOAK_TOKEN,
    clientId = CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET,
    accessTokenRequiresBasicAuth = false,
    requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post, // must POST to token endpoint
    defaultScopes = listOf("roles")
)
```

There are multiple endpoints that I want to secure but the redirect URI can only be set to one URL, in the example below it's `/login/oauth` and `/secret`.

```
    install(Authentication)
    {
        oauth("secretOAuth") {
            client = HttpClient(Apache)
            providerLookup = { keycloakProvider }
            urlProvider = { "/secret" }
        }
        oauth("keycloakOAuth") {
            client = HttpClient(Apache)
            providerLookup = { keycloakProvider }
            urlProvider = { "/login/oauth" }
        }
    }
```

Does it make sense to create multiple of these authentication paths like in the example above or would it be bad practice?
The `/login/oauth` and `/secret` are pointing to the following routes:

```
    authenticate(keycloakOAuth) {
        get("/login/oauth") {
            val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()
                ?: throw Exception("No principal was given")

            createSession(principal)
            call.respondRedirect("/")
        }
    }

    authenticate(secretOAuth){
        get("/secret")
        {
            val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()
                ?: throw Exception("No principal was given")
            createSession(principal)
            call.respondHtml {
                body{
                    h1{
                            +"You accessed secure page!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Functionality wise it works, when the user isn't logged in it prompts them with the login window, otherwise they get to see the secret/their session gets created but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. Is there really no way to change the `urlProvider` based on the accessed URI? Because then I will have to make an authentication for each protected endpoint and that might be a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, it's redundant to have multiple authentication configurations for the same provider because a client can acquire an access token with any. I suggest using the `authenticate` block to just get an access token and save it somewhere. You can use the usual routes for the "secret" resources where you can check a user having an access token.

```
routing {
    authenticate("keycloakOAuth") {
        get("/login") {
            // The endpoint for user login
        }

        get("/callback") {
            val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()

            if (principal != null) {
                // Save access token (principal.accessToken) for further use
            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }
    }
    
    get("/secret") {
        if (!hasToken()) {
            call.respondRedirect("/login")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay this solves half of my problems. What I'd like is keycloak to redirect me to the /secret endpoint after logging in. How does this work in ktor, how can I pass the redirecturi for any secret endpoints dynamically?

The reason why I tried to define multiple oauths in the installation block is that I didn't find any other way to redirect the user to that specific endpoint after authenticating.

Comment: You can redirect a user to any location in the `/callback` handler.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the fast response. So I would redirect the user with this line `call.respondRedirect("/")`. However I'm not sure how to get the original uri in the callback handler, so /secret for example. Is it accessible in the call object? Since I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to get the original URI. You can probably save this information in a client's session https://ktor.io/docs/sessions.html and use it later for a redirect.